# Natural Transformations on an Endofunctor

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 137 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

Is the claim here that $\mu$  being a natural transformation implies that $T \mu$ **and** $\mu T$ are natural transformations as well? How does this follow?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you read the section (II.5) that it refers to about horizontal composition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an arrow $f:x\to y$, there is a square 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T^2 x@>T^2f>> T^2y \\
@V\mu_x V V @VV\mu_y V\\
Tx @>>Tf> Ty
\end{CD}$$
which I'll call $S(f)$. The naturality of $\mu$ is equivalent
to $S(f)$ commuting for all $f$. Suppose it does.

Applying $T$ to $S(f)$ gives 
\begin{CD}
T^3 x@>T^3f>> T^3y \\
@VT\mu_x V V @VVT\mu_y V\\
T^2x @>>T^2f> T^2y
\end{CD}
and as this always commutes then $T\mu$ is natural.

On the other hand,
$S(Tf)$ commutes, and that is
\begin{CD}
T^3 x@>T^3f>> T^3y \\
@V\mu_{Tx} V V @VV\mu_{Ty} V\\
T^2x @>>T^2f> T^2y
\end{CD}
and this says that $\mu T$ commutes.